# How could I add to a link to wordpress manually?

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink

I wanted to ask that is it possible that instead of manually pushing the "add link button" for adding a link, you add a HTML code for this purpose? Lets suppose instead of pushing the button and specifying the name and link address, you add an HTML That after publishing be changed to a link name and a link address?

I pasted a HTML link code code in one of my posts but it didn't turn out to be a correct link at the end.

So would anybody please give me a help about that?

Thank you so much in advance for your answer/s.

Answer (score 0):

put this code in `text`  tab near `visual` tab. where code is present .

Answer (score 0):

You can add HTML if you toggle the Visual/HTML tab above the WYSIWYG editor you are using. Also, read the [Writing Post](http://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Posts) page from WordPress Codex